# How to obtain an object from an arrayList by matching with one of the fields and not by the index in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Good morning.

Currently I have an ArrayList called Account that has several parameters and within it has fields of the ArrayList type (attribIdenCtaUsos), what I want is to obtain certain parameters of this ArrayList Account, which is as shown:

**PostpaidAccount Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PostpaidAccount {

@JsonProperty("billingAccountNumber")
Integer billingAccountNumber;
@JsonProperty("accountId")
Integer accountId;
@JsonProperty("arcoID")
Integer arcoID;
@JsonProperty("initialDate")
Timestamp initialDate;
@JsonProperty("productId")
Integer productId;
@JsonProperty("platformId")
Integer platformId;
@JsonProperty("accountStatusId")
Integer accountStatusId;
@JsonProperty("accountStatusInternal")
String accountStatusInternal;
@JsonProperty("accountStatus")
String accountStatus;
@JsonProperty("internalAccountStatusDescription")
String internalAccountStatusDescription;
@JsonProperty("productName")
String productName;
@JsonProperty("marketName")
String marketName;
@JsonProperty("atribIdenCtaUsos")
private List<T_ATRIB_IDEN_CTA_USO> atribIdenCtaUsos;
```

**T_ATRIB_IDEN_CTA_USO Class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class T_ATRIB_IDEN_CTA_USO {

    @JsonProperty("abrevt_atrib_cta_uso")
    private String abrevt_atrib_cta_uso;
    @JsonProperty("valor")
    private String valor;
    @JsonProperty("fecha_inicio")
    private String fecha_inicio;
    @JsonProperty("fecha_fin")
    private String fecha_fin;
    @JsonProperty("id_atributo_cta_uso")
    private long id_atributo_cta_uso;
}
```

the response Json is like the following:

[image]

Now from the following Json, I need to extract from the ArrayList atribIdenCtaUsos I need to extract the value field that is found where the abrevt_atrib_cta_uso field its valor is equal to TLF, it is always like this, however, it is the case that this value does not always come in position 1 and it can be obtained by means of a getIndex(1).value, but it can be in position 0, for which I need a way to be able to filter that ArrayList by means of the valor abrevt_atrib_cta_uso is equal to TLF

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Also, you can delete all `@JsonProperty` annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream the elements, filter for the one you want, and get its value:

```
String v = myObj.getAtribIdenCtaUsos().stream()
  .filter(obj -> obj.getAbrevtAtribCtaUso().equals("TLF"))
  .map(obj -> obj.getValor())
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values of `abrevt_atrib_cta_uso` are always unique you could declare `atribIdenCtaUsos` as a `Map<String, T_ATRIB_IDEN_CTA_USO>` and use `abrevt_atrib_cta_uso` as the key. Then your lookup is simply `atribIdenCtaUsos.get("TLF");`.